# Discord.py, I can't receive message with @client.command()

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I can't receive message with `@client.command()`.
This is what look like my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='s!')

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    print(ctx.author)

client.run('')
```

Thanks

Comment: It's printing the message onto console. Not sending. Use `ctx.send` for sending messages onto discord

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to do is the name of the author and printing out that.

If you want to send the message the user gave, you can do this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client =  commands.Bot(command_prefix = 's!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  author = message.author

 # "!test" is the command of taking the message. Change with yours.
  if message.content.startswith('!test'):
    print(message.content)
    await test(author, message) #sends to a new method which shows message in channel.

async def test(author, message):
    final_message = message.content[5:] #Slicing of the !test part. You also need to do it.
    await message.channel.send(final_message)

client.run('')
```

Here,

- "!test" is the command of taking the message. Change with yours.
- Slice the command part to show the exact message.

[**Example**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eapCK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ctx.channel.send()` to send the message to the channel where the command was invoked from.

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    ctx.channel.send(ctx.author.name)
```